# Partition a set into 2 subsets

Tags: combinatorics

I was dealing with this problem:

> Consider the set $S=\{1,2,3,\dots,100\}$. We construct two subsets $A$
>   and $B$ with $10$ elements each, such that the elements of $A$ are all smaller than the ones of $B$. How many ways are there to construct two such sets?

The answer is straightforward: $\binom{100}{20}$ But then, this following question came to my mind and I struggled to find an approach.

> Consider the set $S=\{1,2,3,\dots,100\}$. We construct two subsets $A$
>   and $B$ with $10$ elements each, such that; when their elements are
>   arranged in ascending order, each $i$th element of $A$ is smaller
>   than the $i$th element of $B$. How many ways are there to construct
>   two such sets?

I'm not interested in a computational solution; other than that, is there a nice way to solve this?

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ have to be disjoint or can they overlap?

Answer (score 1):

The below assumes that $A$ and $B$ must be disjoint.  It is not clear if that was required or not in the problem statement.

First choose $A \cup B$, which is $100 \choose 20$.  Then you need to find the number of ways to partition $[1,20]$ into two $10$ element subsets subject to the corresponding element condition.  These are the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  Look at the monotonic paths staying below the diagonal.  Think of $n=10$ (the number of elements in $A$).  If there is a right arrow, the next number goes in $A$, if there is an up arrow, the next number goes in $B$  As long as we don't get above the diagonal, we meet the corresponding element condition.  So there are ${100 \choose 20}C_{10}={100 \choose 20}\frac 1{11}{20 \choose 10}$ ways

Comment: @bof:  you are correct I assumed A and B are disjoint in my answer.  I don't immediately see a way to fix it.  I thought about adding $1$ to all the elements in B, but that doesn't seem to work out.  I added a note.